# Is transit visa required for Munich/Frankfurt for a connecting flight?

Tags: germany, transit-visas

I know this question had been asked in the past also and I had read those answers but some of them are outdated and may not hold good now. So, I am just asking it again to get the latest info.

I am holding an Indian passport and with an expired US visa.
Can I travel with Lufthansa without having a transit visa from the USA to India via Munich?

As per this document, it looks an Indian citizen can travel with an expired US visa.

https://www.germany.info/blob/917514/80e28ec8a47bb057c06ca4023b155842/airport-transit-country-list-data.pdf

I also read other conflicting answers which says you can't transit via Germany if you have an expired visa.

My itinerary is  -> Boston - Munich - New Delhi with 3 hours layover in Munich.

Can anyone please help with this.

**Update**:
Today I had sent an email to German consulate in Boston about the same and below is the reply which I had received from them.

```
Dear Applicant,
When leaving the US while holding a valid US resident status (eg. Green Card, Visa), 
no Airport Transit Visa is required.

If your resident status has expired, even if you 
hold an I-797 Approval notice, please note:

The longer the time gap between, the expiration date 
of the visa and the return from the USA, the higher 
the likeliness of facing complications when transiting 
through Germany.

The final decision whether an airplane can be boarded
 or a transit zone can be entered, without a transit 
visa, lies with the Airlines or German Border Police, 
respectively. 
Therefore the Embassy advises clients, whose US-Visa 
has expired to apply for a transit visa.

Please note:

Airport transit privilege does not apply and you 
will need a visitor visa

1. if you have to pick up your baggage and/or have
 to check-in again (please verify with your airline).

2. if you are transiting through two or more airports 
in the Schengen Countries (for example: 
Miami-Frankfurt-Paris-India or  New York-Frankfurt-Munich-India).

3. if you hold an open ticket.

You will find additional information regarding airport 
transit visas on our website here:

https://www.germany.info/us-en/service/05-VisaEinreise/
airport-transit-visa/924624
```

So, I am going to avoid my travel via Germany.

Comment: Can you clarify that you man transit via either Munich **or** Frankfurt, and not both? I.e. either US-Munich-India or US-Frankfurt-India, but **not** US-Frankfurt-Munich-India or US-Munich-Frankfurt-India?

Comment: yeah, i had updated the question. I will be traveling from Boston -> Munich -> New Delhi

Answer (score 6):

It's good that you already found the official information by the German government, but it is better to look up visa requirements in the software *Timatic*, because that's what the airline will use to decide whether they let you board or not, and it also gives you the most up-to-date information.

I like the interfaces provided by [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx) and [Olympic Air](https://www.olympicair.com/en/Info/before_and_during_flight/Timatic), because they are simple and easy to use. Both should show you the exact same information.

In your case, the following is relevant:

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of India transiting through Frankfurt (FRA) or Munich (MUC), arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight **within 24 hours** to a third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - have a used, valid or **expired visa** issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania, **USA** or United Kingdom, and
> - be **returning from the country that issued the visa**, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for their next destination.

You say that you are indeed returning from the USA, so all conditions should be satisfied and you should not need a visa. Just make sure you don't book a connection like JFK-FRA-MUC-DEL, because that would require you to enter Germany for the domestic flight!

Comment: For now I am assuming all this information will hold good and they will let me board the flight. I will be booking the tickets today. Lets hope for the best.

Comment: If in doubt, you can always check again once you're closer to your date of travel, but these regulations don't usually change that quickly.

Comment: I received a reply from German Consulate today , they had advised me not to travel without a visa.

Comment: thanks for your answer. but I am not accepting it as an answer now after I receive the reply from German consulate in Boston. I am also going to avoid my travel via Germany .

Comment: @Saurav They appear to tell everyone to get a visa, even when it isn't really necessary. You do not actually need a transit visa for this itinerary. unless one of the exceptions that the embassy listed applies. Usually it's people who book a flight through both FRA and MUC that run into problems. This requires a regular Schengen short stay visa, not just a transit visa.

Comment: @Saurav Hmm, did you make it clear that you would only be transiting and staying in the transit zone? If you did, then I can only imagine they told you to get a visa because they don't want to be held liable if something goes wrong for some reason. Did the consulate state why you should get a visa?

Comment: @Michael, I checked that I met all of their requirements to not to get a transit visa for my connecting flight but I am still not sure why they had advised getting a transit visa. Maybe its a standard reply to this type of situation.

Comment: @Mophotla , Yes, i made it clear about my situation. To me it looks like a standard reply to these types of situations. Consulate didn't mention any reas why I should get a visa. Sad situation both document and cosnulate reply contradict each other.

Comment: @Saurav I looked at the reply from the consulate and if I had to guess, I would say they told you to get a visa for Germany because you only have an expired US residence permit, not an expired US visa. While visas may be expired, residence permits do appear to have to be valid in order to grant you visa-free transit through Germany.

Answer (score -2):

Nationals of  the following countries are required  to be in possession of an airport transit visa  when passing through the international transit  area of airports in  Germany: Afghanistan Ghana Lebanon Bangladesh India Mali South S udan Democratic Sri  Lanka Republic of the Congo Iran Nigeria Sudan Eritrea Iraq Pakistan Ethiopia Syria Jordan *1 Somalia Exceptions: Turkey Nationals of  the above  named  countries Do  NOT  require an airport transit  visa  if *2 1.  they hold  a valid  visa  for  the United  States of  America,  or 2.  they hold  a used  valid  or  expired  visa  issued  by  the USA  and  return from the USA and  travel to a non-Schengen  Member  State  within  24  hours after  the  expiration of  their  visa,  or 3.  they hold  one  of  the following  residence permits: ×  Form I-551 permanent resident card  (valid  for  2  to 10  years), ×  Form I-551 Alien  registration receipt card  (valid  for  2  to 10  years), ×  Form I-551 Alien  registration receipt card  (no expiry  date), ×  Form I-327 Re-entry  document  (valid  for  two  years  —  issued  to holders of a I-551) ×    Resident alien  card  (valid  for  2  or  10  years or  no expiry  date.  This document  guarantees the holder’s return only  if his stay  outside the USA has not exceeded  one  year), ×  Permit to re-enter  (valid  for  two years.  This document  guarantees the holder’s  return only if his stay outside the USA  has not exceeded  two years),   ×  Valid temporary  residence stamp in a  valid  passport (valid  for  one  year from  the  date of issue). Please note that  the advance parole (I-512) and the  approval notice (I797) are  not  valid documents for visa  free  airport  transit.  An  aiport transit  visa  must  be  obtained. 4.  they hold  a valid  visa  for  a Schengen  Member  State,  Bulgaria,  Canada,  Croatia, Cyprus,  Ireland,  Japan,  Romania  or  UK,  or 5.    they hold  a used  valid  or  expired  visa  issued  by  Bulgaria,  Canada,  Croatia, Cyprus,  Ireland,  Japan,  Romania  or  UK  and  return from  the country  of  visa issuance and  travel to a non-Schengen  Member  State. Please note that  an  airport  transit  visa  only  allows  a  short  stay in  the international transit  area  of  some airports: ×  Frankfurt/Main (open  24  hours) ×  Munich (open 24 hours) ×  Hamburg (4:30 a.m.  -  11:30  p.m. only) ×  Düsseldorf  (6:00 a.m.  -  9:00  p.m. only) and  if the airline has arranged  the transit beforehand  with the authorities responsible for  cross-border security  (the Federal  Police) ×  Cologne/Bonn (4:30  a.m.  -  11:00  p.m. only) ×  Berlin (06:00  a.m.  -  11:00  p.m. only) at Berlin-Tegel,  for  Air Berlin passengers only.  The airline  has to arrange the transit beforehand  with the authorities responsible for  cross-border security  (the Federal Police).  The connection time must  be at least 75  minutes. Airport  transit  privilege does  not  apply and  you  will need a  visitor visa  if 1.  you have to pick  up your  baggage and/or  have to check-in  again  (please verify with  your  airline) or 2.  you are transiting  through two or  more airports  in  the Schengen  Countries (for example:  Miami-Frankfurt-Paris-India  or  New  York-Frankfurt-Munich-India) or 3.    you hold an  open ticket.

Comment: Nationals of India need airport transit visas to transit through German airports unless exceptions apply, even if they don't need to pass through immigration. Airlines are required to check this before the traveler is allowed to board the flight _to_ Germany.

Comment: Nationals of  the following countries are required  to be in possession of an airport transit visa  when passing through the international transit  area of airports in  Germany: Afghanistan Ghana Lebanon Bangladesh India Mali South S udan Democratic Sri  Lanka Republic of the Congo Iran Nigeria Sudan Eritrea Iraq Pakistan Ethiopia Syria Jordan *1 Somalia Exceptions: Turkey Nationals of  the above  named  countries Do  NOT  require an airport transit  visa  if *2 1.  they hold  a valid  visa  for  the United  States of  America,  or 2.  they hold  a used  valid  or  expired  visa  issued  by  t